# Android procedurally change Gadget Mode

Tags: android, usbmanager

Is there a way of selecting the gadget mode from an android app, specifically for when connecting to hosts?  I.e. Can I request the host OS goes into RNDIS mode? Or `UsbManager.USB_FUNCTION_MIDI`?

I can't seem to find any way in documentation for selecting the requested gadget mode.